# Cakephp 3 language switcher link

Tags: cakephp

How to create a link that allow users to switch website language using cakephp 3.1?

I have created a multilingual website but I googled for creating a link to switch languages but without luck.

Comment: This might be of help: [i18n](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/docs/I18n/I18n.md)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the instruction how to change locale at runtime: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#changing-the-locale-at-runtime

Knowing that you - can create an action (i.e. in AppController) that changes language and saves that data in cookie, you can do for instance (simple example) in your AppController:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);

    $lang = $this->Cookie->read('lang');

    if (empty($lang)) {
        return;
    }

    I18n::locale($lang);
}

public function changeLang($lang = 'en_US')
{
    $this->Cookie->write('lang', $lang);
    return $this->redirect($this->request->referer());
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<?= $this->Html->link('Change language to PL', ['action' => 'changeLang', 'pl_PL']); ?>
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution for 3 days, your answer is the best. It worked perfectly.  The answer after 7 years is still good. I am working on Cake 4.4. Thank you.